# App crashes when start

Tags: android

My android app crashes when I start here is the code
I have tried it on an different device
and it compiles fine

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    int userAns;
    int ran1;
    int ran2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ran1 =(int)(Math.random()*50+1);
        ran2 =(int)(Math.random()*50+1);
        TextView number1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        number1.setText(ran1);
        TextView number2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        number2.setText(ran2);
        ans =ran1+ran2;

    }
   public void sendMessage(View view){
       String userAnsS = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString();
       userAns= Integer.parseInt(userAnsS);
       if (userAns == ran1 + ran2) {
           return;
       }
```

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: `ran1` is integer value?

Comment: You have to typeCast ran1 and ran2 to String Type, so as to provide it in textView

Comment: when sendMessage() method u r calling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
number1.setText(""+ran1);
number2.setText(""+ran2);
```

Or use

```
number1.setText(String.valueOf(ran1));
number2.setText(String.valueOf(ran2));
```

In your case

`public final void setText (int resid)`

```
// looks for a resource with the id mentioned
// if resource not found you get resource not found exception
```

What you want

`public final void setText (CharSequence text)`

```
 // Sets the string value of the TextView. 
 //ran1 and ran 2 is of type int so use String.valueOf(intvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strings when setting texts to TextView `number2.setText(String.valueOf(ran2));`

Answer (score 0):

See android [developers website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for setText usage

You need

```
setText(CharSequence text)
Sets the string value of the TextView.
```

The setText method accepts CharacterSequence

And Strings are CharSequences, so you can just use Strings with setText Method.

So you can use both `number1.setText(String.valueOf(ran1));` or `number1.setText(""+ran1);`

Answer (score 0):

The ans variable is not declared as int type i.e 
int ans=ran1+ran2

The setText method of the textview uses the string as a variable and therefore use the following
number1.setText(string.valueOf(ran1));
number2.setText(string.valueOf(ran2));